# How to access functional option function name

Tags: go, reflection

Given the following program, how would I go about accessing the functional options function names using reflection?

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "path"
    "reflect"
    "runtime"
    "strings"
)

type config struct {
    count int
    name  string
}

type OptionFn func(cfg *config)

func WithCount(count int) OptionFn {
    return func(cfg *config) {
        cfg.count = count
    }
}

func WithName(name string) OptionFn {
    return func(cfg *config) {
        cfg.name = name
    }
}

func printOptions(optFns ...interface{}) {
    for _, optFn := range optFns {
        fmt.Println(funcName(optFn))
        optType := reflect.TypeOf(optFn)
        fmt.Println(optType)
    }
}

func main() {
    printOptions(WithCount(4), WithName("golang"))
}

func funcName(opt interface{}) string {
    n := runtime.FuncForPC(reflect.ValueOf(opt).Pointer()).Name()
    return strings.TrimSuffix(path.Base(n), path.Ext(n))
}
```

Currently `printOptions` outputs

```bash
main.main
main.OptionFn
main.main
main.OptionFn
```

The expectation is that `printOptions` would output

```bash
WithCount
WithName
```

The use case is to create a mocking, testing, and assertion mechanism for functional options.

Comment: You can't do that. The functional options are closures, and have no name.

Comment: Moreover, you shouldn't need to do that for testing/assertion purposes.  If you want to validate that you have an `OptionFn` instance that sets `cfg.count`, call it and see if `cfg.count` is updated.  Test behavior. Not implementation details.

Comment: @JonathanHall I'm planning to expose this as a library that would have no visibility into the option/config types. My library would expose a mocking interface and internally, I'd want to compare the expected call with the actual call.

Comment: I know the functional options are closures and don't have names but they are wrapped by functions which do have names (WithCount and WithName)

Comment: They are not wrapped by the other functions, they are returned by the functions which no longer exist at the point you want to inspect them.

Comment: You should re-consider whether mocking even makes sense (it usually doesn't), and how to do it, since what you're attempting just isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

Declare options as a struct type containing the name and function fields.

```
type Option struct {
    name string
    fn   func(cfg *config)
}
```

Use the name field to get the name.

```
func printOptions(opts ...Option) {
    for _, opt := range opts {
        fmt.Println(opt.name)
    }
}
```

Set the name field in the option factory functions:

```
func WithCount(count int) Option {
    return Option{"WithCount", func(cfg *config) {
        cfg.count = count
    }}
}

func WithName(name string) Option {
    return Option{"WithName", func(cfg *config) {
        cfg.name = name
    }}
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/yxgXAAww77q